# MySQL - Display Sum Where with Join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table

Table news:

```
id_post | news      | id_user
3       | IT news   | 1 
4       | game news | 2
```

Table user:

```
id_user | username
   1    | bocah
   2    | gundul
   3    | ganteng
```

And Table vote

```
id_vote | id_post | id_user | LIKE
10      | 3       | 2       | 1
11      | 3       | 3       | 1
12      | 3       | 1       | 1
```

And this is my sql query:

```
SELECT id_vote, u.id, username, SUM(v.like) AS like FROM vote v
LEFT JOIN user u ON v.id_user=u.id 
LEFT JOIN post p ON v.id_post=p.id_post 
WHERE YEARWEEK(p.time)=YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY like DESC LIMIT 4
```

I want to display top user based total like where news is in current week. In my expectation user 1, bocah will display **3** **LIKE**. And the problem is user 1, bocah, only receive 1 LIKE.

Any answer?

Comment: can you show the expected o/p?

Comment: The output should be like this:
username bocah LIKE 3

Comment: Anyways here id_user 1 is not having like more than 1 right then how can you expect that likes 3

Comment: i think with using sum(v.like).. but it doesn't work. user 1 is the author of post with id_post 3. So user 1 have 3 LIKE. But in my query it just show 1 LIKE

Comment: You question has news table and your query has Post table. Can you share the post table too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query.It should work as per your expectation.

```
SELECT u.id_user, u.username, SUM(v.like) AS like
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN news n ON u.id_user=n.id_user 
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.id_post=n.id_post 
WHERE YEARWEEK(v.time)=YEARWEEK(NOW()) 
GROUP BY u.id_user
```

Comment: In vote has no time, time is only in post, but thanks for the answer, i accept this

Answer (score 0):

remove id_user column from vote table. (conflict, you are showing different post for user 2 in vote table.)
 then make your query like this, i guess it will help u.

```
select sum(`likes`) as `Like`, user.user_id , user.id_user from vote v
LEFT JOIN news n ON v.id_post=n.id_post 
LEFT JOIN user u ON n.id_user=u.id_user 
where <your time condition>
group by v.id_post
order by `like` desc limit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  n.*,
  u.`username`,
  (SELECT SUM(`like`) FROM vote WHERE id_post = n.`id_post` ) AS likes
FROM news n
INNER JOIN `user` u ON u.`id_user` = n.`id_user`
WHERE YEARWEEK(n.time)=YEARWEEK(NOW())
ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 4;
```

From what I can see from the tables, you want the top votes per news post likes right?
I assume the datetime field is in the news table or is it when the vote was done?

result:

```
id_post |news      |id_user | username | likes

3       | IT News  |1       | gandul   |3
4       |game news |2       | bocah    |(NULL)
```